# Python 2.7: Building Sub Lists from Specific Ranges within a Master List Without Replacement

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

That was a mouthful!

As part of an experiment, I generate an Array of 448 items. Each index (item) looks like this: `{'stimulus bin': 1, 'label': 2, 'stimID': 1, 'fileName': 'stim1.png'}` and should be selected as a whole.

Now, that master list is subdivided into 8 categories each containing 56 items (ie: 0-55, 56-112,..., 391-447.

Here's what I'd love to be able to do:

I would like to create 14 sub-lists that will randomly select 4 indices from each of the 8 categories in the master list and remove them from the Master list so that a specific index can only be selected once (and add that selection to the appropriate list.

each list can be named something arbitrary like list1 - list14

I should end up with 14 lists of 32 items each.

I'm pretty stuck as to how to go about this. I'm somewhat new to Python, though not completely clueless I think.

Any suggestions would really help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of 448 items (which are opaque, for this algorithm's purposes). Their initial order determines their category, with each group of 56 corresponding to a different category (so there are 8 categories total).

You want to get an output of 14 lists, each of which has four items from each category.

Here's an outline for how I'll do it:

1. First, slice the list to get the separate categories.
2. Next, shuffle the category lists using `random.shuffle`.
3. Next, use `zip` to turn the 8 lists of 56 items into 56 lists of 8 items.
4. Next, take the values four at a time, using `zip` again on a repeated iterator.
5. Finally, combine values into the final lists using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

The code:

```
import itertools
import random

def make_lists(input_list):
    categories = [input_list[i:i+56] for i in range(0, 448, 56)] # 8 lists of 56
    for c in categories:
        random.shuffle(c)
    selections = zip(*categories) # 56 tuples of 8
    it = iter(selections)
    by_four = zip(it, it, it, it) # 14 tuples of 4 tuples of 8
    results = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)) for lst in by_four]
    return results
```

Here's an example of running this on a list of integers:

```
>>> for lst in make_lists(list(range(448))):
    print(lst)

[47, 104, 114, 197, 269, 297, 368, 422, 23, 60, 128, 184, 242, 334, 375, 407, 6, 110, 160, 198, 244, 320, 383, 430, 27, 78, 153, 202, 272, 322, 376, 436]
[55, 67, 167, 211, 232, 284, 363, 420, 48, 73, 136, 190, 259, 332, 351, 440, 44, 64, 142, 180, 263, 294, 361, 419, 15, 83, 157, 207, 255, 280, 350, 398]
[12, 102, 124, 199, 252, 314, 341, 432, 53, 89, 147, 170, 265, 329, 369, 409, 36, 56, 155, 206, 241, 290, 366, 441, 5, 94, 140, 223, 262, 321, 388, 394]
[1, 81, 129, 203, 227, 319, 382, 421, 43, 57, 120, 173, 233, 292, 337, 428, 8, 58, 143, 196, 267, 301, 356, 403, 34, 101, 151, 194, 230, 300, 352, 435]
[11, 74, 112, 174, 250, 316, 391, 418, 38, 72, 132, 172, 261, 310, 338, 429, 13, 66, 144, 188, 275, 299, 347, 446, 31, 71, 119, 189, 248, 304, 367, 413]
[18, 109, 123, 208, 246, 323, 355, 416, 30, 85, 126, 192, 279, 303, 378, 406, 0, 103, 149, 179, 236, 333, 357, 408, 39, 75, 139, 187, 277, 285, 339, 400]
[9, 62, 121, 193, 271, 335, 385, 412, 19, 86, 116, 217, 264, 315, 380, 411, 42, 105, 154, 222, 256, 293, 387, 439, 29, 97, 130, 212, 273, 311, 348, 417]
[35, 90, 148, 186, 231, 331, 359, 433, 45, 76, 158, 182, 253, 317, 379, 405, 46, 106, 125, 218, 237, 325, 381, 444, 40, 84, 156, 205, 251, 283, 346, 397]
[17, 95, 159, 185, 268, 281, 353, 393, 54, 61, 134, 215, 258, 318, 342, 424, 22, 100, 135, 220, 254, 306, 365, 442, 41, 91, 137, 210, 257, 288, 370, 426]
[14, 68, 141, 177, 226, 330, 374, 415, 51, 87, 113, 216, 240, 287, 354, 437, 49, 96, 115, 200, 243, 313, 336, 404, 24, 92, 131, 214, 238, 296, 386, 447]
[32, 82, 162, 219, 274, 326, 358, 396, 7, 88, 118, 176, 224, 289, 384, 402, 16, 111, 122, 213, 234, 308, 340, 425, 10, 108, 164, 183, 225, 295, 373, 410]
[20, 77, 127, 195, 266, 312, 372, 392, 33, 70, 133, 168, 276, 328, 360, 427, 26, 99, 161, 209, 278, 291, 390, 401, 21, 80, 166, 181, 235, 298, 345, 399]
[52, 107, 117, 201, 270, 302, 377, 395, 37, 93, 150, 175, 228, 282, 344, 434, 25, 69, 163, 221, 239, 305, 343, 445, 3, 59, 152, 178, 247, 309, 364, 414]
[50, 65, 138, 171, 260, 324, 371, 443, 2, 63, 146, 191, 245, 286, 389, 438, 4, 98, 145, 204, 249, 307, 362, 431, 28, 79, 165, 169, 229, 327, 349, 423]
```

Note that the order of the items within the output lists is not completely random, but which list any given item falls into will be. If you want the items in the output to be ordered by category, you could perhaps reverse the order of steps three and four, but I think it would end up a bit more awkward, since there's not an easy way to do the `zip(it, it, it, it)` trick in a list comprehension (you'd need two list comprehensions, I think, one to make the iterator and a second to do the `zip` once you have a name for `it`). If you need the output lists to be in any given order, I suggest sorting each of them with an appropriate `key` function.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you very much :)

Just wondering, when you write categories = [input_list[i:i+56] for i in range(0, 446, 56)] did you mean (0,448,56) ? Why 446?

Comment: @Ben: Whoops, yeah, the 446 was a typo. Conveniently though, it didn't effect the results, since the step size of 56 (the last value yielded by the `range` is 392).

Answer (score 0):

Your master list of 448 items can be implemented as a list of lists of dictionaries. They don't need to have names at all (if you want them to, you could just add another field to the dictionaries).

```
masterList = []

for i in range(0, 8):
    for j in range(0, 56):
        category = []
        item = {'stimulus bin': 1, 'label': 2, 'stimID': 1, 'fileName': 'stim1.png'}
        category.append(item)

    masterList.append(category)
```

Then use `list.pop(i)` (removes an item from index `i` of a list and returns it) and `randint(a, b)` (random integer between `a` and `b`, inclusive on both ends) to remove four random objects from each category and stick them into a sublist.

```
from random import randint

def sublist(masterList):
    result = []
    for category in masterList:
        for i in range(0, 4):
            result.append(category.pop(randint(0, len(category))))
```

That function creates one sublist.